# Assign tooltip to jquery dialog box X

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to give tool tip to the jquery dialog box that has X mark on top right corner of the pop up. its an default icon that loads for jquery dialog box.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ui has an option for the close tooltip: [closeText](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText)

Here's a fiddle if you want to see it in action: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcXEx/3/)

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    closeText:"NEW TOOLTIP"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this tooltip_g.js in script tag in your JSP.

### I have used it like this and it creates a question mark on the top right corner and pop ups a message.

```
<a href=""
javascript:void(0);" onmouseout="hideTooltip()"
onmouseover="showTooltip(event,'your message');return false;"><img
src='<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/images/help.jpg")%>' />
```